# a-frame superhands custom hand model

Tags: components, custom-controls, aframe

I'm trying to develop a VR formation using aframe-super-hands-component, and I can't figure out how to use a custom glb hand model instead of the regular one.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific on your question https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: please consider closing the question then

Comment: I thought I had found a way using the inspector:

<a-entity id="rhand" sphere-collider="objects: a-box" super-hands="" hand-controls="right"  gltf-model="./mymodel.glb" scale="1 1 1" rotation="0 0 0"></a-entity>

Unfortunately it only works on pc but not inside the headset.
What I'm tryng to achieve is to replace the generic hand model provided by the component by a custom Gltf model of myne. Sorry but I can't be more specific.

Comment: please write that on the question. Have you read the link I posted? We can allways try to be on the position of someone busy that knows nothing about our actual problem.

Comment: if you found difficult the first link try reading this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and again wellcome to StackOverflow

Comment: I think the question was plain and simple for anyone who knows about aframe and super-hands-component, which I guess would be the target audience for this question anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found a workaround for it. Using the a-frame-super-hands component (index laser example), I shrank the controller scale :

```
<a-mixin id="controllers-right" oculus-touch-controls="hand: right" gltf-model="./Models/Hand.glb"  scale="0.05 0.05 0.05"></a-mixin>
```

Then I scaled up my glb model to regain the lost size, placing it in order to have the controller model hidden inside my gltf model.